# Prevent Internet Explorer from grabbing focus

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, iframe, focus

I've been stumped on this problem for a week. After consulting various questions and failing to find a resolution I decided to finally ask here.

Project Info: Using ASP Net and Visual Studio. 
Element causing issue: iframe being loaded from Microsoft Power BI

Issue: when I open my webpage in Internet Explorer or Firefox, the iframe will grab focus (I think this is focus) and force the page down to the iframe after loading.

Possible resolution 1: prevent the iframe from ever grabbing focus.
Possible resolution 2: implement a lazy load system so the iframe doesn't load until the user scrolls to it. This would also be satisfactory.

Background: We are using ASP Net Master and child pages. The issue occurs on a child page. So any advise on where to place a script with solution would be helpful as well.

This is a common issue with Power BI embedded. For example, if you visit the official Microsoft blog where they have embedded an iframe, the "jump" will occur if you open this link in Internet Explorer: https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-power-bi-publish-to-web/

Here's what the embedded code looks like:

```
<iframe width="455" height="345" src="https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiOTAzYzU2NGUtNzc0Ny00NTU4LWJmNWMtNjJhMWJiOTcwMjdiIiwidCI6ImY4NTA5NjYwLWNiMTMtNGU2Yy1hYzhjLWNlZWNjZDIzNzkyYSIsImMiOjZ9"></iframe>
```

I have been so stumped on this. Any advice would be so appreciated!

Comment: Have a look at the navigation url, does it have a # in it?..... find the element in the document that has that id value... eg #bireport .. it will be at the top of your iframe element.... remove or change its id attribute.

Comment: I think 'that' feature is called hash navigation. Regards.

Comment: @RobParsons I can confirm that this happens even when the iframe src attribute does not contain a hash ('#')